# Why isn't ebp register saved on MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Using this C++ code:

```
struct Class
{
    void* vtable[1];
};

struct Object
{
    Class *klass;
};

extern Object* obj;
typedef Object* (*ObjectFunction)(void*);

extern "C" Object* DoStuff ()
{
    return ((ObjectFunction)obj->klass->vtable[3])(nullptr);
}
```

With compiler version: `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547 for x86`
And compiler args: `cl.exe source.cpp /MD /c /bigobj /Ox /Oy- /Fasource.asm`

```
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547.0 

    TITLE    C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\source.cpp
    .686P
    .XMM
    include listing.inc
    .model    flat

INCLUDELIB MSVCRT
INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

PUBLIC    _DoStuff
EXTRN    ?obj@@3PAUObject@@A:DWORD            ; obj
; Function compile flags: /Ogtp
_TEXT    SEGMENT
_DoStuff PROC
    mov   eax, DWORD PTR ?obj@@3PAUObject@@A    ; obj
    push  0
    mov   eax, DWORD PTR [eax]
    mov   eax, DWORD PTR [eax+12]
    call  eax
    add   esp, 4
    ret    0
_DoStuff ENDP
_TEXT    ENDS
END
```

Notice that the `ebp` register isn't pushed into the stack, and the caller address is not saved into the `ebp` register. This makes `CaptureStackBacktrace` function not see the caller of this function in the stacktrace. Why does the compiler not emit function prolog here?

Comment: /Ox and Oy- are conflicting options.  Follow the documentation guidance and favor /O2 instead.

Comment: [/Ox Full Optimization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ox-full-optimization)

Comment: @HansPassant - [(1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/oy-frame-pointer-omission) *"Specifying /Oy- after the /Ox, /O1, or /O2 option disables /Oy, whether it is explicit or implied."* and [(2)](https://godbolt.org/g/XnMiTz) neither /O1 nor /O2 change anything.

Comment: Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know.